# Error Info: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'geoprocessing value object' and 'str'

Tags: python, arcmap, arcpy

The line where this error was called from is:

```
exportpng = exportfolder + os.sep + name + '.PNG'
```

Error Info:
unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'geoprocessing value object' and 'str'

Can't remedy it with the other responses/questions from stackoverflow....

Comment: Are exportfolder and name strings? If not try casting them to string

Answer (score 2):

Inspect your variables.  You can do this by dropping into a [debugger](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) on the line before the error.

One of your variables is not a string.  Either `exportfolder` or `name`.  check ikt out

Answer (score 2):

I think this is related to use of arcpy.GetParameter() instead of arcpy.GetParameterAsText() for this specific instance since the type of former is geoprocessing value object whereas the latter is str.